# Killing X-related processes when CrashPlan is running

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, x11, backup

I am currently running Ubuntu Server 12.04, but this applies to all flavours of Linux really.

This server does a bunch of things and is controlled remotely via ssh. Some time ago I have installed XFCE for those times when I didn't really feel like commandlining or to speed up some program configuration. It's off most of the time and I only launch it when I need it.

Today I installed CrashPlan to have my other computers on the network backup to the server. For those of you who don't know it, CrashPlan comes with two services, one is the actual backup engine and one is the GUI. So I installed in on the server, launched the GUI to configure it and then killed X (`sudo service lightdm stop`).

But now every time I try to login remotely with RDP from my Windows machine (`xdrp` is installed on the server) I am able to connect graphically to the server, which means that all the X-related processes are still running.

What have I forgotten? Is it possible to stop running the CrashPlan GUI service and have it never start anymore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What makes you think X-related processes are still running? When you log in remotely xrdp (re-)connects you to your GUI environment. If you don't have one running already then `xrdp-sesman` will cause a GUI environment to get initialized. (If you want to prevent that you could `sudo service xrdp stop` although it will likely come back on re-boot unless you prevent that.)

Why not just ssh into the Ubuntu server and do a `ps -ef` to assure yourself that no processes are running that you do not expect? In the case of CrashPlan you would see CrashPlanService all the time but you only see CrashPlanDesktop if the GUI is running.

Comment: It makes more sense now. I didn't know that launching `xrdp` recreated the GUI environment.

Comment: Right, so the GUI does not autostart (nor does the service, for that matter). Running `sudo service xrdp stop` closed X apparently, because I am not able to connect remotely anymore. Thank you :)

Comment: @sim below is correct "What he says isn't true that it recreates the desktop." Perhaps the edit makes that clearer.

Answer (score 2):

I would take a look at this guide from the CrashPlan website titled: [CONFIGURING A HEADLESS CLIENT](https://support.code42.com/CrashPlan/Latest/Configuring/Configuring_A_Headless_Client). It spells out the details of how one would go about installing CrashPlan for use in a headless situation, which is really what you want.

#### But I just want to disable the GUI

If you're using a desktop environment such as GNOME you can launch the configuration dialog, `gnome-session-properties` and configure what apps are auto started when you login.

[image: ss of auto]

Simply uncheck or remove it all together to stop CrashPlan from launching. In the above I'm showing a similar GUI that gets launched by DropBox, but the method is the same.

Comment: I upvoted your answer anyway, but it's not exactly what I am looking for (I had already read that guide). I am interested to know how to disable (and optionally re-enable the GUI service) rather than how to configure CrashPlan in headless mode. This way I could `xrdp` to the server without having to change the app's configuration from the remote machine to connect to the headless CrashPlan running on the server.

Comment: @user1301428 - thanks. I still don't really understand your issue then. I use XRDP for both home and work and have a pretty extensive understanding of it. I'm not sure how the other A even answers your actual Q either. What he says isn't true that it recreates the desktop. When you RDP into the system and run a program and then disconnect and then come back, the app is still running, correct? So the CrashPlan GUI is still running.

Comment: @user1301428 - if you do not want the CP GUI to run regardless of RDPing in or not, I'd look to your DE's auto starting of apps and simply disable CP there. I'll add an example to this A.

Comment: @user1301428 - let me know how you make out.

Comment: Ok I tried it and I could confirm that the GUI service does not autostart. Thank you!

Comment: @user1301428 - so this is actually the more correct A, but it's your call.

Comment: Equally correct. The other user answered first though, so he deserved an extra :)

Comment: @user1301428 - as I said your call 8-)